# How to convert xlsx files to csv files in RStudio? Need to convert multiple workbooks all with multiple spreadsheets

Tags: r, excel, csv, xlsx

Trying to write an R script that will convert multiple xlsx workbook files within a folder while also converting the sheets within the workbook as separate csv files.
Looking for a single script to automatically apply code to all workbooks and their spreadsheets.

Comment: Please see [How to make a great reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

For reading Excel files, there are [several packages](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/).

I personally am happy with the [xlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html) package, which you can use to read Excel files, as well as their individual sheets. [This article](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r) looks like it will give you the gist of it.

Each worksheet you read out you should then be able to export to CSV files by using R's built-in `write.csv` (or `write.csv2`) method.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to convert a single xlsx workbook to multiple csv files.
Note that type conversions are not guaranteed to be correct.

```r
xlsx_path <-"path_to_xlsx.xlsx"
sheet_names <- readxl::excel_sheets(xlsx_path)
# read from all sheets to a list of data frames
xlsx_data <- purrr::map(
    sheet_names,
    ~readxl::read_excel(xlsx_path,.x,col_types = "text",col_names = FALSE)
)
# write a list of data frame to csv files
purrr::walk2(
    xlsx_data,sheet_names,
    ~readr::write_csv(.x,paste0(xlsx_path,"-",.y,".csv"),col_names = FALSE)
)

# csv files will be saved as:
# path_to_xlsx-sheet1.xlsx, path_to_xlsx-sheet2.xlsx, ...
```

If you need to apply this function to many xlsx files. Use `list.files()` to get the path to all xlsx files. And write a for loop or use another map function to iterate this process.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Would you mind including where I would be inputting my own data? Today is honestly my first day of coding and I am very lost!

Comment: As you mentioned it's your first day coding, you could need more guidance than a stack overflow answer. Please read @Alex 's answer as he included a tutorial, which should be very helpful to you. After you understand the basic workflows, you will find the answers here make more sense.

Comment: Just looking into that now! Of course stumbled across another array of errors but making process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rstudio it is possible that you already have the package `readxl` installed. They have many workflows for common usecases explained here: https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/readxl-workflows.html

They also provide this nice code snippet to do what you are asking for:

```
read_then_csv <- function(sheet, path) {
  pathbase <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(path))
  df <- read_excel(path = path, sheet = sheet)
  write.csv(df, paste0(pathbase, "-", sheet, ".csv"),
            quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
  df
}
path <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
sheets <- excel_sheets(path)
xl_list <- lapply(excel_sheets(path), read_then_csv, path = path)
names(xl_list) <- sheets
```

Answer (score -3):

If you go to [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/) and put "excel" and "xls" in the search bar, you 'll get a list of packages and functions which might help.