# R: Need help converting excel sheets to csv, while properly converting column types & checking .xls or .xlsx extension

Tags: r, excel, csv, readxl

I'm fairly new to R & scripting and I'm trying to write a script that will convert each sheet in an excel file to its own csv file. This script will be used on many excel files that won't all have the same number of sheets, number of rows/columns per sheet, and may have columns with empty values. Also, the script will probably be used by other people at work besides myself, so I don't want to use too many packages that they will have to install.

The following is an outline of what I want the script to do:

1. Take user input for file name
2. Check whether the file has extension .xls or .xlsx
3. Append correct extension (.xls or .xlsx) to file name
4. Read each sheet in the excel file
5. Keep column data types the same (I explain more later)
6. Write each sheet to its own csv file

I searched online & tried various methods to get excel sheets converted to csv files, but I didn’t have much luck with most of the methods I found. The one method that got me most of the way there is [Yifu Yan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330955/how-to-convert-xlsx-files-to-csv-files-in-rstudio-need-to-convert-multiple-work). However, exactly as he mentioned, the column types did not convert correctly.

I tried modifying Yifu Yan’s code a bit, trying to figure out the column type conversion myself, but was unsuccessful. Here is the code I used (with readxl & purrr packages):

```
file <- readline("Enter file name: ")
# Use if/else, for, or while loop to check file extension, which will replace “.xlsx” in the following line with the determined extension
path <- paste0(file, “.xlsx”)
sheet_names <- readxl::excel_sheets(path)
df <- purrr::map(sheet_names,  ~readxl::read_excel(path, .x, col_types = "guess", col_names = FALSE))
purrr::walk2(df, sheet_names, write.csv(.x, paste0(file, "-", .y, ".csv"), col_names = FALSE))
```

When I tested the code with an excel file, I found that some of the columns converted fine, but others didn’t. Here is an example of what the data should have looked like after conversion:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2233.09 | 501 | 1234567 | ab | 3/20/2011 6:09:17 |
| 1122.09 | 502 | 1234569 | ac | 3/20/2011 6:12:25 |

What it actually looked like:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2233.0900000000001 | 501 | 1234567 | ab | 40622.25644675926 |
| 1122.0900000000002 | 502 | 1234569 | ac | 40622.258622685185 |

The 3 things I want help with:

1. How to ensure the column types/values stay exactly the same during the conversion process
2. What function I can use to check the file extension (I can figure out how to write the loop myself if need be)
3. If possible, use base instead of purrr. I would prefer if the only non-base package is readxl (or xlsx), but its fine if not

EDIT:
Since I couldn't get anything else to work while only using one package (besides tools), I will just use readxl & tidyverse (includes readr & purrr). Not ideal, but does what I need it to.

Comment: I would try using readr rather than readxl directly because (for me) it usually identifies the dates correctly as dates.  The other option might be read in everything as characters and then convert the dates.  If you want the numeric column to only show two decimal places you can use round().

Comment: Assuming that your excel sheets have column names in the first row the issue might be that you read your data using `col_names=FALSE`. This way the column names are read as the first row and hence all columns are read as characters. hence, try with `read_excel(..., col_names = TRUE)`. And of course could you rewrite your code using base R, use `lapply` for `map` and e.g. `Map` instead of `walk2`. But note that in `Map` the function comes first.

Comment: @Elin the original code (from Yifu Yan) used col_types="text" which read everything as text values, but when I used that it didn't seem to affect anything and my columns were still converted incorrectly in my columns.

Comment: @stefan I don't know if it is the purrr package, but trying col_names=TRUE in both the read & write functions (with col_types="guess") gives me the "expecting numeric" error. Switching col_types to text gives "unused argument (col_names=TRUE)" error for the write function. And when I delete col_names from the write function, it returns the error "object .x not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Column Types

Number 1 is the hardest and I fear you  won't find a one fits all solution. Most of the Excel readers I know try really hard to determine the column type. This is not an easy task, because Excel cells contain arbitrary values, and R must find a suitable heuristic to get the proper cell type. This guessing works in my opinion most of the times and even in cases where it doesn't it is often the case that R is right and just the formatting in Excel is misleading.

So for example your first column looks totally valid to me. R recognizes the number format and reads in the floating point number.

In floating point arithmetic ([cf. Circle 1 - Falling into the Floating
Point Trap](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) the two values are indeed the same:

```r
all.equal(2233.0900000000001, 2233.09)
# [1] TRUE
```

For your date problem it is quite similar. Internally in Excel dates are store as numbers (and times as fractions), in the following screenshot both columns `A` and `B` contain the same numbers, but column `B` hast datetime format:

[image: Screenshot of an Excel file, in Column A you see number 1, 1.5 and 2. In Column B you see a formula taking the same values as Column A. Column B hast datetime formatting showing that Excel uses numbers internally to represent dates and fratcions to show time]

The conversion is a bit tricky and on e needs to know that Excel dates start at `1899-12-30` (for whatever reason)

[image: xkcd comic mocking the fact that Excel starts dates on the 30th of December 1899]

```r
as.POSIXct(40622.25644675926 * 24 *60*60, origin = "1899-12-30", tz = "GMT")
# [1] "2011-03-20 06:09:17 GMT"
```

With all this subtleties and as you are anyways interested in CSV format (which does not know about types other than numbers or text), why not using text for all columns?

```r
readxl::read_excel(path, .x, col_types = "text")
```

### File Extension

You can use `tools::file_ext`. `tools` is a base library so should be installed anyways, but the implementation is easy enough:

```r
function (x) {
  pos <- regexpr("\\.([[:alnum:]]+)$", x)
  ifelse(pos > -1L, substring(x, pos + 1L), "")
}
```

Thus, you can easily get the file extension then by `tools::file_ext(file)`.

### `base` Loops

you can use `lapply` as a direct "replacement" (actually it is the other way round, `purrr::map` is a replacement of `lapply`) for both `map` and `walk`:

```r
df <- lapply(sheet_names,  
             \(.x) readxl::read_excel(path, .x, col_types = "text", 
                                      col_names = FALSE))
lapply(names(df), 
       \(.y) sheet_names, write.csv(df[.y], paste0(file, "-", .y, ".csv"), 
                                    col_names = FALSE))
```

Comment: After testing my code using your suggestions, here are my results so far: 1) I have been able to check the file extension. 2) I have written a loop that fixes the date conversion in each new csv file using the as.POSIXct function. 3) When using lapply instead of map & walk from the purrr package, I can't seem to get the script to write the csv files. When I run the script using lapply, it doesn't return any errors and appears to run the same as the script using purrr, but no csv files appear in my folder once it's done.